# How to switch between activity in android if one of activity is called by an handler

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, switch-statement

My problem borns when i call

```
 Intent i = new Intent(c.getApplicationContext(),ActivityMulti.class); 
 c.startActivity(i);
```

It generates the exception mentioned below:

```
10-02 17:54:26.037: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(905): java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{package.com/package.ActivityMulti}:  
java.lang.InstantiationException: package.ActivityMulti
```

This is called in an handler generate like this:

```
Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
Bundle b = new Bundle();    
msg.setData(b);
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

The second Activity is a simple one:

```
public class ActivityMulti extends Activity{

    public ActivityMulti(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
         TextView tv = new TextView(this);
         tv.setText("This is activity multi");
         setContentView(tv);
        //ImageButton info = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.info);
        //info.setImageResource(R.drawable.info2);
        //this.setContentView(R.layout.view_multi);
    }

    }
```

Why that exception is generated? Can you help me?

EDIT: 
This is my manifest:

```
.
.
.
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".ActivityMulti"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT 2:

I Solved! the problem was in constructor of the second Activity.. There is no need of it!

```
public class ActivitySingle extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    init();
}
private void init(){
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("This is activity single");
    setContentView(tv);
    //ImageButton info = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.info);
    //info.setImageResource(R.drawable.info2);
    //this.setContentView(R.layout.view_multi);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the activity you are starting in the Manifest file?

It's not important if you are starting it from `Handler`, since you have provided the right context for using `.startActivity()`. I think you have missed to add the activity in the manifest.

Comment: I added <activity android:name=".ActivityMulti"></activity> and i use in startactivity the context passed from first activity